# How to create small letters above the line of text

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create **superscript** (small letter above the line of text) in eclipse.

**Example:** m/s<sup>2</sup> where 2 should display as power of `s`.

Comment: Why do you say in `eclipse`? Do you mean show it in an android app text view right?

Comment: With views or Graphics2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, use `Html.fromHtml()` method:

```
TextView outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
outputText.setText(Html.fromHtml("m/s<sup>2</sup>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String forgettext = "Your text";
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(forgettext);
span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, forgettext.length(), 0);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of TextView is tvSample, add this code in your oncreate Method.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>m/s <sup>2</sup></p>"));
```

In android, You have an option to set a HTML content for a Text View. Using this, You can create any font style within a Text View